# compiling nginx with page speed error

Tags: nginx, mod-pagespeed

Hi all why do I get this error when compiling Nginx with page speed

```
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/myhomedir/ngx_pagespeed-release-1.6.29.5-beta/nginx-1.4.2'
make -f objs/Makefile manpage
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/myhomedir/ngx_pagespeed-release-1.6.29.5-beta/nginx-1.4.2'
sed -e "s|%%PREFIX%%|/usr/local/nginx-1.4.2|" \
    -e "s|%%PID_PATH%%|/usr/local/nginx-1.4.2/logs/nginx.pid|" \
    -e "s|%%CONF_PATH%%|/usr/local/nginx-1.4.2/conf/nginx.conf|" \
    -e "s|%%ERROR_LOG_PATH%%|/usr/local/nginx-1.4.2/logs/error.log|" \
    < man/nginx.8 > objs/nginx.8
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/myhomedir/ngx_pagespeed-release-1.6.29.5-beta/nginx-1.4.2'
```

Comment: Well this is dumb someone make me down if i was not confused in the first place ill not ask the question

Comment: I don't see any error message in that snippet of output...

Answer (score 0):

Whit that log I think no body can help you, Few information....

Error 1 =  1 EPERM Operation not permitted.  An attempt was made to perform an operation limited to processes with appropriate privileges or to the owner of a file or other resources.

More info: http://www.daemon-systems.org/man/errno.2.html

Comment: what am i to do den